# How do I get a background image to scale in android studio?

Tags: android, css, xml

So I am trying to import a custom image as the background of an android app however it does not fill in all of the edges. The option I have seen is to set a second layout to be a frame layout and then place an image view within it with additional coding along the lines of android:scaleType="centerCrop". This will not fill the entire screen up for me however, heres a screenshot of what ends up happening -

[image]

Heres the xml code being used:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundImgr"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Another issue is that different users use different resolutions so the background image has to be able to accommodate them all without being cut off. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Can you use mipmap to do this?

Comment: I've tried mipmap and end up with the same problem in terms of scaleing

Comment: If you want to force it to fit the screen then set the scale type to `fitXY`. For your other issue, you'd have to create variations of your pic targeting different screen densities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set ScaleType fitXY and add   `android:adjustViewBounds ="true"` 
Please use `android:src="@drawable/` instead background .I hope it will helps you.